# Can you not call "Montage_Play" in a custom character movement component? C++ UE4

Tags: c++11, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to call Montage_Play from my custom character movement component. But my pointers to the anim instance keep failing. Is this not allowed? I've tried casting the AnimInstance and trying to get the mesh.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend it, but yes you can totally get an anim instance from a movement component. From memory you'd want to get a pointer to the owner, cast it to a character, call `ACharacter::GetMesh` and then there's a skeletalmesh function to return an anim instance.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying! Where would you recommend calling it? Do you think i should just create my own anim instance and go based off that? EDIT: Im trying to use root motion to have my player dodge over the network!

Comment: The typical setup is to use an anim state machine for movement anims, though it's not a hard rule. If you want to use montages for movement then playing them via the movement component is probably fine.

Comment: I see, I've seemed to encounter another error though. Everything seems to work as intended but the animation isnt replicating? The movement is though.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to manually replicate anims. Movement itself is replicated by the base movement component. The simplest thing to do is replicate an anim sequence pointer that denotes the current anim. Have that be set by a server rpc and call your montage play function on replication. That will come with slight input lag on clients, which can be sorted out with network prediction if you choose.

Comment: @George sorry to bother you, do you happen to have a link so I may try this? Im pulling my hair out over here lol. Or if theres an easier way ill restart. I never used state machines because whenever i tried to make my character roll the right distance it wouldnt work. Whether i used velocity to push the character or launch character. Regardless though, the animations never replicated. I created my own character movement component as well. Its frustrating because sprinting works perfectly fine while dodging doesnt. So I must be doing something wrong here.Everything i google, nothing comes up